# CSS Vertical Align Text with Multiline Ellipsis when Needed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed size container in which I wish to display variable-length multiline text with known font size, line height, etc.

- If the text fits inside the container: it is centered vertically
- If it does not fit inside the container:

  - Any overflow is hidden om a per-line basis (i.e. so that last line is either fully displayed or hidden but not half-hidden)
  - Text is displayed from the start (instead of only the middle portion showing up due to vertical centering)
  - An ellipsis is appended to the text (either real one or fake one via CSS hack)

As a bonus, if there are more dynamic solutions with scrolling text or "Read more..." auto-inserted via JavaScript, please mention these to or post a link.

The solution should work or at least have graceful fallbacks for older browsers starting from IE9 (don't care about older versions of IE).

Example usage: comment inside a fixed-size speech bubble:

[image: comment inside a fixed-size speech bubble]

EDIT:

I suppose I could use

```
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   line-height: @line-height;     /* fallback */
   max-height: @max-height;      /* fallback */
   -webkit-line-clamp: @line-number; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

But, first of all, it's webkit-only. And secondly and more importantly, how do you then center text vertically when it *does* fit inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property in your css for this.  As far as vertically align, I always recommend [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and using `display: flex;` with `align-items: center`.

EDIT:  Flexbox does not work in IE9.  In that case, I would recommend wrapping the text in another div and giving it `margin: auto;`  That will put it in the middle of the div.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply but your answers has several problems: Text-Overflow: ellipsis does not work for multiple lines. And display:flex with central alignment will hide both the first and the last lines when the text is bigger than the container (in such cases I want the text to be displayed starting from the first line).

Comment: I've used `text-overflow: ellipsis;` several times, and it always worked with multiple lines for me.  Not sure why it wouldn't work for you, unless you wrapped the text in a div and put the class on the wrong div.  Also never had that issue with flexbox.  I'll create a plunker and see what I can figure out.

Comment: The issue is you need to add `white-space:nowrap` this causes the text into 1 line and adds ellipsis. But I need the text to be displayed over several lines, so that `white-space:nowrap` is not an option, but without it there is no ellipsis.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I remember now, I used webkit functionality that won't work in IE9.  Sorry.